# ResultSet returning null on valid result

Tags: java, sql

I have a query as such

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalAmount
FROM
    CurrentApplications
WHERE
    CurrentApplications.resp_id IN (1)
    AND FinalOutcome_date BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-30 23:59:59'
    AND (FinalOutcome >= 1 AND FinalOutcome <= 2)
    AND (FIND_IN_SET(14, app_category)
    OR FIND_IN_SET(15, app_category)
    OR FIND_IN_SET(26, app_category))
```

It returns the value of 10 within MySQL Workbench.

Now I'm retriving the query as such:

```
insideResultsSet = insideStatement
                .executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalAmount  FROM CurrentApplications  WHERE CurrentApplications.resp_id  IN(1)  AND FinalOutcome_date  BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-30 23:59:59' AND (FinalOutcome >=1 AND FinalOutcome <= 2)  AND(  FIND_IN_SET(14, app_category) OR  FIND_IN_SET(15, app_category) OR  FIND_IN_SET(26, app_category)) ");
        while (insideResultsSet.next()) 
        {
            mResultValues.put((String)(Reflection("Subdivision_of_land_" + RANGE_NAMES[EachMap.getKey()])),
                    insideResultsSet.getDouble("TotalAmount"));

            Fn.Out(insideResultsSet.getDouble("TotalAmount"));
            Fn.Out_Stop("SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalAmount "
                    + mCurrentApplications
                    + " WHERE CurrentApplications.resp_id " + mResp_authority + " " + "AND "
                    + FIELD_FinalOutcome_date + " " + EachMap.getValue() + "AND (" + FIELD_FinalOutcome
                    + " >=1 AND " + FIELD_FinalOutcome + " <= " + FIELD_FinalOutComeORRAHighNumber + ") "
                    + getCommaSeachSQL_AppCategory_Multi(new int[]{14,15,26}));
        }
```

The Fn.Out_Stop query is working 100% but the result is not even valid when I output the result directly.

The result is 0 and the object type is null. Can anyone explain what's going on here? Strange error for me as this has worked fine for over 400 other queries..

Comment: Are you sure you want `getDouble()` when getting a `COUNT(*)`?  Would you ever expect a count of 10.5?

Comment: count(*) return an int and not a double but you use getDouble(). Maybe that's your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name is probably not `"TotalAmount"`.  Either try using indexed getters like `getLong(1)` or put double quotes around the column name in the query to force case:

`"SELECT COUNT(*) AS \"TotalAmount\" ... "`

Without quoting the column name in the query the database is free to change the case.